# FileWritter write integers as illegal characters

Tags: java, filewriter, illegal-characters

i'm currently writting an algorithm who write another algorithm.
For this i'm using the FileWritter class and this worked fine until i tried to write integers in the file.

`fileWriter.write(1);` print `` (edit : you can't see the character in here)  that intelliJ  interpret as : `Illegal Character U+0001` (every number has a different name of illegal character)

When i'm doing `fileWriter.write("1")` this work fine.

Does the problem come from Intellij or do i have to convert every integers to String ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically `Writer.write(int)` doesn't do what you expect it to. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write(int)) says:

> Writes a single character. The character to be written is contained in the 16 low-order bits of the given integer value; the 16 high-order bits are ignored.

So you're writing U+0001, just as IntelliJ is saying.

It's not the greatest API in the world (it would be better to accept `char` for a single character) but it *is* behaving as designed.

Basically, yes, you need to convert everything to text.

Answer (score 0):

The `FileWriter.write(int)` method, which is inherited from `OutputStreamWriter.write(int)`, writes a single character to a file. The input `int` is the ASCII or Unicode representation of the character. For instance, writing `fileWriter.write(65)` writes the letter `A`, as `A`'s ASCII value is 65. This could also be written as `fileWriter.write('A')`, as the character `A` is represented in memory as the number `65`. If you want to write an integer to a file, you will need to call `fileWriter.write(Integer.toString(i))`, where `i` is the value you want to write. Alternatively, if `i` is a single-digit positive number, you can write `fileWriter.write('0' + i)`, as adding `'0'` to such a digit converts it into its corresponding character.